# Catch 404 type Exception on web pages that dont generate a 404 Head

Tags: java, html, http-status-code-404, httpurlconnection

I am trying to find out if a web page exists utilizing Java, if it responds with code 200 (Page exists).

I can also find out if a page (doesn't exist) by getting response code 404.
My problem is some sites don't give a 404 and will either redirect or show a page that shouldn't? exist as provided in the sample below.

I don't know if this is just because i don't know enough about the html response codes or java.

Any help would be appreciated in helping to get an error code instead of a 200 on these pages, or catching an exception. (sorry if I'm not making sense).

```
public class TestMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Test test = new Test();
    test.UrlCheck();        
}
}
```

Test Class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Test{

public void UrlCheck(){ 

    try{    
    URL url = new URL("http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.au/5000");
    HttpURLConnection urncon = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection (); 
    urncon.setRequestMethod ("HEAD"); 
    urncon.connect(); 

    int code = urncon.getResponseCode();    
    if(code == 200)
    System.out.println("Page Found");

    }catch(MalformedURLException mue){
        mue.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My problem is some sites don't give a 404 and will either redirect or show a page that shouldn't ...

... with a 200 status code.

There is no generic solution to this.

If the website chooses to respond with a 3xx or a 200 for a page that does not exist, then there is no generic way to distinguish the response page from a "real" page.  Indeed, the response page may be indistinguishable from a "real" page ... even for a human being.

The best you can hope to do is to code your application to recognize the behaviour of the specific site (or sites) that you are crawling; e.g. by looking for characteristic strings in the response page.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input, and though i pretty much get the same answer from everyone of "can't do generic", the tick has to go somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will not be able to.do tjis on some sites - they will have custom 404 handlers, page that will redirect you to there "not found" (good practice). In this case 404 eill never return to you, but valid page.

Answer (score 0):

Since the site in question says the page exists, there's not much you can do about it. If it's only for certain sites, I recommend you search the response body for something that indicates it doesn't match your criteria (e.g. "No posts"). Going to http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.au/500067890 gives a 404, so maybe the example page really does exist?

```
// lazy and untested example. Can't remember if getContentEncoding gives character encoding

String charset = urncon.getContentEncoding();
if (charset == null) {
    // Sane default
    charset = "UTF-8";
}
String data = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(urncon.getInputStream(), charset);
if (!data.contains("foobar")) {
    throw new IOException("Site not liked");
}
```

edit: added package name for IOUtils and fixed method name.

Comment: The sample is not working at first play, and while it would be good for a generic response, the internet is if anything a jungle :) So you might be onto something with searching in the body per web site.

Answer (score 0):

There is no fool proof way to achieve what you want, depends on how sites handle 404. They might simply supress it and provide you with a custom response.

Answer (score 0):

If it comes back with a 200 then the page exists, there's not really a generic way of catching that if that's what the webmaster chooses to do.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly all sites will send 404 for "Page not found" error. In case they are changing the response it is very unlikely that they will set as 200 because 200 is for success.

But as marked by others, you cannot identify this in your code unless the site owner notify others.